# Show different values two objects of one class

Tags: java, reflection, field

I use in my java tests asserting actual and expected values. Ofcouse, throw assert exception if two objects is different. But I want to know, what different.

If anybody know java library, answer me.

Simple: I want print to console all different fields: public, protected, private (primitive types). Object's class can have many inherited class. I want log only simple fields: String, Number, Boolean, Char, items of array[] / collections.

If field is another class, don't log it value (toString function). I want show different only simple fields for this subclass.

For Collections show only different values.

For example:

```
class A {
private String a;
protected int b;
}


class A1 { 
private int c;
private String d;
}

class B extends A {
private byte[] array;
private List<A> collection
private A1 a1;
}
```

So, we compare to object class B.
If different fields a/b, I show:

```
field: a. values: Tom / Jerry.
```

If don't equals a1, then I want know, what field:

```
field: a1.c. value: 10 / 12.
```

Similarly for array and collections.

I can parse all fields for all inherited classes. I get each field, get field type. If it simple (String, Number, Boolean...) log different values.

If it's another subclass with own field I can recursively repeat for extract all fields.
But I have issue: how I can extract from field value, if it's array or collection?
I get from Field::get() object.

How I understood and get from object -> Type[] or Collection{Type} and that class is Type?
If I can it, then simple. I compare arrays/collections by size. If size equals, then start equals each item.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use reflection

Comment: @selig, ofcouse :). I have two large questions. Is exists ready library for this? If no, then how I can parse field as array/collection.

Comment: @YShinkarev: Just to be clear, `B` will not inherit `a`, since `a` is `private`.

Comment: @Rahul Bobhate, yes, you are right, but anyway still opened question

Answer (score 0):

To know if you field's type is an array, use `isArray()` method from `Class`.

From Collection{Type}, the type of the field is 'Collection', 'Type' is a generic. You can do extra check if you want on the generic by retrieving it with `((ParameterizedTypeImpl) myField.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()` but that's probably not necessary.